# How do I create and use a remote git branch?

Tags: git

How do i create one with my name on it?

```
remotes/origin/my_name
```

when i do this:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/my_colleague
```

And how do i use that? `git checkout`?

i only know git pull commit push.. and it's my first time to use branches or remote branches

i tried `git remote add my_name git@my_url`, but it doesnt look the same..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `git branch -a` told me that you have two remote branches `origin/master` and `origin/my_colleague` (`origin/HEAD` really does not count).  To checkout a local branch of `origin/my_colleague` you can `git checkout -b my_colleague origin/my_colleague`.  This creates a new local branch, based on the `origin/my_colleague` remote, and checks it out.  To go back to `master` (I know you are currently on `master` because of the `*`), you can `git checkout master`.